# HTML/CSS : Add Responsive Box+Text Over Image

Tags: html, css

I have a website [www.weardenali.com](http://www.weardenali.com). A part of the site has an image banner which I want to be overlayed by a Colored Box and some text, just like how [Bellroy.com](http://bellroy.com)  has theirs.

This is what I have, a failed code which isn't responsive :

**Wear Denali (my site):**
[image: Denali]

**Bellroy:**
[image: Bellroy]

This is the code i am using now :

```css
.image-banner-content.content-left {
  padding-left: 1% !important;
}
.sf-animation.image-banner-content,
.sf-animation[data-animation="none"].image-banner-content {
  bottom: 80% !important;
}
a.link:hover,
a.link:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color:#F03E3E !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-bottom: 60%; float: left; display: inline-block; padding: 0px 10px 5px 10px; background-color: #ffffff; position: relative;">
  <h3>
    <span style="color: #0e3559;">
      Designed by Urban Adventurers
    </span>
  </h3>
  <h4>
    <a href="http://weardenali.com/" class="link" style="color: #0e3559; float: left; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: 1.2px;">
      &gt; SHOP NOW
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
```

I appreciate any advice/pointers.

Comment: Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking another question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your image banner was done in a kinda sorta ok way... This should work:

```
<!--- code for the image banner --->
<div class="MyAdvertisement">
    <h3>Designed by Urban Adventurers</h3>
    <a href="http://weardenali.com/">
       <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
       SHOP NOW
    </a>
</div>
<!--- end code for the image banner --->
```

Note that I added Font Awesome code for the > you had in there. Using glyphs the way you did is annoying for non-sighted users. Google Font Awesome. It's nice.

I'm not sure what you want to do exactly. I'll give you css for pixel values, but if you want responsive as is 'scales with the browser', use percentages.

```
.MyAdvertisement {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 200px;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
background: white;
}
```

If you can't put your code where I suggested, you are going to have to tell us more about your site code before anyone can help you in any meaningful way.

Good luck & have fun.

Comment: David, thanks for the reply. its a woo-commerce site, so I tried placing the HTML code on the image banner , and add your CSS Code in the Custom CSS.  The result was  - It created a box , but it did not "wrap" to the edge of the image banner much like Bellroy did. Tried changing the position of the text from absolute to other alternatives but still did not do the trick.

Comment: The DIV is where you should focus your efforts. That is what provides the 'box'. Once you have that right, you can go nuts on the text without much risk.

If you need it to stretch to both sides of the box it is in, make it 100% wide.

If that does not work, I'll need to know how the image banner itself was coded.

Comment: The 100% will be 100% of whatever the div is inside of. So, probably 100% of the width of the image banner's container (most likely a div or li element. BUT, if the banner uses nefarious trickery, it is possible it, itself does not know how wide it is, and therefore can't 'tell' your div how wide it should be. If that makes sense to you.

Comment: Tried setting di DIV but no matter what i try, it just couldn't wrap itself around the image. Perhaps because it is not working according to Image banner size?

Comment: I'm confused; do you need the div to lay on top of an existing image banner, or do you need to add the image as well?

Comment: Tried setting di DIV but no matter what i try, it just couldn't wrap itself around the image. Perhaps because it is not working according to Image banner size?

The banner uses shortcodes since its a theme , but just to give you an idea : 

[spb_image_banner element_name="textbox" image="15244" image_size="full" content_pos="left" content_textalign="center" animation="none" animation_delay="200" link_target="_self" el_class="bottommover" width="2/3" el_position="first"]

Comment: I'm confused; do you need the div to ....

I need the DIV to lay on top of an existing image banner.

Comment: The div you copied from my reply is inside another div on your site (image-banner-content-left) that has width: auto; So, 'my' div is going to be 100% width of that div.

Make that div 100% width, and 'my' div too, and 'my' div will scale with it.

I must say: that's some messy css you have there. I think in time you may want to hire a company to re-do it all for you, because this is going to be headache upon headache for you. (No worries, we aren't local to you, not advertising my company here.)

Comment: Do you use the browser's 'inspect code' tool? Can be very helpful. Just right-click on your website and you should get something like 'inspect code'.